# Background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)) is not covered whole background

Tags: html, css

Please help needed with my code. I really cant make it work. I spent over 4 hours just to figure out how to extend the background linear colour to fully cover the background. I have images and `h1` and `p` tags as you can see in the code is only covering half of my image background not all the way down.

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

What am I missing?

```css
#bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5));
}
#khalifa {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#bottom h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: maroon;
}
#bottom p {
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#bottom img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}
#empire {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom">
  <div>
    <div id="khalifa">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/khalifa.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
      <h1>Burj-Al-Khalifa</h1>
      <p>The Burj Khalifa (Arabic: برج خليفة‎‎, Arabic for "Khalifa Tower"; pronounced English /ˈbɜːrdʒ kəˈliːfə/), known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, United Arab Emirates. It is the tallest structure in the
        world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft)</p>
    </div>

    <div id="empire">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/empire.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
      <h1>Empire State</h1>
      <p>The Burj Khalifa (Arabic: برج خليفة‎‎, Arabic for "Khalifa Tower"; pronounced English /ˈbɜːrdʒ kəˈliːfə/), known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, United Arab Emirates. It is the tallest structure in the
        world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft)</p>
    </div>

    <div id="royal">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/oneworld.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
      <h1>Burj-Al-Khalifa</h1>
      <p>The Burj Khalifa (Arabic: برج خليفة‎‎, Arabic for "Khalifa Tower"; pronounced English /ˈbɜːrdʒ kəˈliːfə/), known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, United Arab Emirates. It is the tallest structure in the
        world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft)</p>
    </div>

    <div id="empire">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/kingdom.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
      <h1>Empire State</h1>
      <p>The Burj Khalifa (Arabic: برج خليفة‎‎, Arabic for "Khalifa Tower"; pronounced English /ˈbɜːrdʒ kəˈliːfə/), known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, United Arab Emirates. It is the tallest structure in the
        world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft)</p>
    </div>

    <div id="khalifa">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/chrysler.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
      <h1>Burj-Al-Khalifa</h1>
      <p>The Burj Khalifa (Arabic: برج خليفة‎‎, Arabic for "Khalifa Tower"; pronounced English /ˈbɜːrdʒ kəˈliːfə/), known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, United Arab Emirates. It is the tallest structure in the
        world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft)</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the css id's #empire, and #khalifa to use a display of inline-block instead of using floats, and adjusted their width of 50% to calc(50% - 2px).

```css
#bottom{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 background-repeat: repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: fixed;
 background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5),rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5));
}
#khalifa{
 height: 100%;
 width: calc(50% - 2px);
 display: inline-block;
}
#bottom h1{
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: maroon;
}
#bottom p{
 text-align: justify;
 padding: 20px;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
#bottom img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 700px;
}
#empire{
 width: calc(50% - 2px);
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom">
   <div>
    <div id="khalifa">
     
     <a href="#"><img src="images/khalifa.jpg" alt=""></a>
     <h1>Burj-Al-Khalifa</h1>
     <p>The Burj Khalifa (Arabic: برج خليفة‎‎, Arabic for "Khalifa Tower"; pronounced English /ˈbɜːrdʒ kəˈliːfə/), known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, United Arab Emirates. It is the tallest structure in the world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft)</p>
    </div>
    <div id="empire">
     
     <a href="#"><img src="images/empire.jpg" alt=""></a>
     <h1>Empire State</h1>
     <p>The Burj Khalifa (Arabic: برج خليفة‎‎, Arabic for "Khalifa Tower"; pronounced English /ˈbɜːrdʒ kəˈliːfə/), known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, United Arab Emirates. It is the tallest structure in the world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft)</p>
    </div>
    <div id="royal">
     
     <a href="#"><img src="images/oneworld.jpg" alt=""></a>
     <h1>Burj-Al-Khalifa</h1>
     <p>The Burj Khalifa (Arabic: برج خليفة‎‎, Arabic for "Khalifa Tower"; pronounced English /ˈbɜːrdʒ kəˈliːfə/), known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, United Arab Emirates. It is the tallest structure in the world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft)</p>
    </div>
    <div id="empire">
     
     <a href="#"><img src="images/kingdom.jpg" alt=""></a>
     <h1>Empire State</h1>
     <p>The Burj Khalifa (Arabic: برج خليفة‎‎, Arabic for "Khalifa Tower"; pronounced English /ˈbɜːrdʒ kəˈliːfə/), known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, United Arab Emirates. It is the tallest structure in the world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft)</p>
    </div>
    <div id="khalifa">
     
     <a href="#"><img src="images/chrysler.jpg" alt=""></a>
     <h1>Burj-Al-Khalifa</h1>
     <p>The Burj Khalifa (Arabic: برج خليفة‎‎, Arabic for "Khalifa Tower"; pronounced English /ˈbɜːrdʒ kəˈliːfə/), known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, United Arab Emirates. It is the tallest structure in the world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft)</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>

</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> just add a div like `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` because you used floats in your css, so you have to clear those floats. after clearing floats it works fine, i just added that c

```css
#bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5));
}
#khalifa {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#bottom h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: maroon;
}
#bottom p {
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#bottom img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}
#empire {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom">
  <div>
    <div id="khalifa">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/khalifa.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
      <h1>Burj-Al-Khalifa</h1>
      <p>The Burj Khalifa (Arabic: برج خليفة‎‎, Arabic for "Khalifa Tower"; pronounced English /ˈbɜːrdʒ kəˈliːfə/), known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, United Arab Emirates. It is the tallest structure in the
        world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft)</p>
    </div>

    <div id="empire">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/empire.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
      <h1>Empire State</h1>
      <p>The Burj Khalifa (Arabic: برج خليفة‎‎, Arabic for "Khalifa Tower"; pronounced English /ˈbɜːrdʒ kəˈliːfə/), known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, United Arab Emirates. It is the tallest structure in the
        world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft)</p>
    </div>

    <div id="royal">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/oneworld.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
      <h1>Burj-Al-Khalifa</h1>
      <p>The Burj Khalifa (Arabic: برج خليفة‎‎, Arabic for "Khalifa Tower"; pronounced English /ˈbɜːrdʒ kəˈliːfə/), known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, United Arab Emirates. It is the tallest structure in the
        world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft)</p>
    </div>

    <div id="empire">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/kingdom.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
      <h1>Empire State</h1>
      <p>The Burj Khalifa (Arabic: برج خليفة‎‎, Arabic for "Khalifa Tower"; pronounced English /ˈbɜːrdʒ kəˈliːfə/), known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, United Arab Emirates. It is the tallest structure in the
        world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft)</p>
    </div>

    <div id="khalifa">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/chrysler.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
      <h1>Burj-Al-Khalifa</h1>
      <p>The Burj Khalifa (Arabic: برج خليفة‎‎, Arabic for "Khalifa Tower"; pronounced English /ˈbɜːrdʒ kəˈliːfə/), known as the Burj Dubai before its inauguration, is a megatall skyscraper in Dubai, United Arab Emirates. It is the tallest structure in the
        world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft)</p>
    </div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```